# Asp.Net.Core 1.0 Kestrel Increase size of post request

Tags: asp.net-core

I have Asp.Net.Core 1.0 project which run under Kestrel web server.There are a some post request from .net desktop client which should working with big request. How I can increase size of post request in this case. I had tried [this one](https://forums.asp.net/t/2100265.aspx?How%20to%20increase%20upload%20file%20size%20in%20ASP%20Net%20Core). All else what I found are for IIS and Core1.1 - 2.0. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Set, It is about Core 1.1 and higher. My project is Core 1.0

Comment: So it seems like a good time to migrate to 1.1 or 2.0

Comment: Kestrel 1.0 didn't have a limit. Only the form reader did. What's the error you get?

Comment: Tratcher, I have a 404 error when I do request more ~25 Mb, but when I try do request like ~10 Mb  all is Ok.